# Object detection api training issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

System information

```
OS WIN 10 Processor : i5-4440 3.10GHz RAM 8

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): pip install TensorFlow
version (use command below): b'v1.10.0-rc1-19-g656e7a2b34' 1.10.0
Python version: 3.6.6
```

Describe the problem

I am trying to train object detection api using `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28`.

I am facing with issue with object detection training. After ~400 steps the training stops because of a path problem while the script create the path:

```
path - C:\Users\z\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\training_dataturk\models\model\export\Servo\temp-b'1538897129'
```

----the error screen shot that happened twice before stopping
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jum9p.png)

Comment: Did you make sure you have all the files required in place / or one of your data file is not corrupted ?

Answer (score 0):

After ~400 steps you are saving your checkpoint to a particular location make sure the path you mentioned is correct:

You can try

`C:\\Users\\z\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow\\Lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\models\\research\\object_detection\\training_dataturk\\models\\model\\export\\Servo`